# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /post/new/ - Post has no author

Tags: django, django-views

I have implemented allauth for user registration and now I am trying to associate the current_user to a post when its being created. When I press 'Submit' I get 'Post has no author' clearly the posts don't recognize the user.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  content = models.TextField()
  date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

View:

```
def create_post(request, pk=None):


form = PostForm(request.POST)

  if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.author(request.user)
    post.save()
  else:
    form = PostForm()

  context = {'form' : form}
  return render(request, 'blog/create_post.html', context)
```

I could really use some pointers, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `author` instance of the `.instance` wrapped in the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def create_post(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-a-view')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'blog/create_post.html', context)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.